# Lumen generate token without verifying username and password

Tags: laravel, jwt, lumen, tymon-jwt

I am trying to generate token by verifying other fields and table rather than email and password of user table. I am using `tymon jwt` library.

I have three fields that need to be verified to authenticate the user

```
 table::where(["id"=>"1","mobile"=>"123","otp"=>"asdf"])->get();
```

So If I found the rows matching this condition in table then I want to authenticate the user and generate valid token with required claims.

What I have tried so far is :

```
//after check for three fields in DB. If row matches then, $id and $contact are variable from DB.
$customClaims = ['id' => $id, 'mobile' => $contact];

$payload = JWTFactory::make($customClaims);
```

When trying this I got `JWT payload does not contain the required claims`.

So how to authenticate user with three field and generate valid token with  required claims and `$customClaims`.

### Edited

```
 public function verifyOTP(Request $request) {
    $otp = $request->otp;
    $schoolid = $request->schoolid;
    $parent_contact = $request->contactNum;
    $verifyOTP = OTP::where(['schoolid' => $schoolid, 'parent_numb' => $parent_contact, 'otp' => $otp])->get();
    if ($verifyOTP) {

        $customClaims = ['schoolid' => $schoolid, 'parent_numb' => $parent_contact];

        $payload = JWTFactory::make($customClaims);

        $token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);
        return $token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share all related code ?

Comment: @C2486 please refer to full code in edited section.

Comment: What you are looking for is `\Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::fromUser($user, $customClaims = [])` where `$user` is some kind of entity with `id` field available. The error you got here is because given claims does not contain required ones - 'iss', 'iat', 'exp', 'nbf', 'sub', 'jti'. You can fill them manually or use the given method.

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys why don't you write an answer if you know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In this case **Crypt** will become so handy, I do not know if you want to do any authentication later. Crypt will help you encrypt and decrypt.

Make trait or any other class, you do not have to worried much on Encrypt and Decrypt, Crypt can take care. I built Mobile API using **Crypt**

Encrypt:
Crypt::encrypt($value);

Decrypt:
Crypt::decrypt($value);

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/encryption

Comment: encryption and decryption is not only the thing JWT does. JWT need to authenticate based on that fields and verify with server secret key also.

Comment: Yes. Like wise encrypt decrypt and lifetime of those depends on how you want to handle. Depends on how you create or  how you architect it.

Comment: Is this even an answer to the question above? How does it solve the OPs problem of missing claims in the JWT?